# what is mime type its not working as i m using application/pdf to sending in iphone

Tags: iphone, email, pdf, mime

MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

```
    [picker setMessageBody:@"Invoice Report Pdf File" isHTML:NO];



    NSMutableData *pdfData =[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    [picker addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:self.pdfName];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change mime type according my code, it will help you.

```
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data]; UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, bounds, nil);
```

Then at some point in the future you'll need to pass that `pdfData` to the `MFMailComposeViewController`.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *vc = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease]; [vc setSubject:@"my pdf"]; [vc addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"image/pdf" fileName:@"SomeFile.pdf"];
```